# The notification for inbox and achievements is a bit misplaced

Tags: bug, status-declined, top-bar

The notifications we get on the inbox and achievements icon in the top-bar seems to be a bit misplaced. Here is a snapshot of it.

[image: Misplaced Notification]

It seems to be misplaced by only a few pixels, but it seems to be misplaced nonetheless. I'm using *Chrome 36.0.1964.2 dev-m* on a *Windows 7* machine.

Comment: Development releases of browsers are not supported; unless you can reproduce this on Chrome 34 this is not something the devs will look into. It is probably a bug in the Dev Channel build, not a Stack Exchange problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Ahh I see. I did not know about that actually. I'm not able to reproduce this on my Firefox browser though which is a stable release and not a beta or dev release. VTC :)